# What does Google Chrome do When It Finds Two Variables or Functions With The Same Name?

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome

I was just wandering what google chrome does when it finds two variables with the same name, for my case this would be: [See the part code with repeated variables](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105880594/data.txt) which is a small part of code from this [code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105880594/full.txt)
My problem is that placing Cannon 1 (its id is 'Cannon1') works fine but placing the gold collector (its id is 'goldC1') doesn't, what is going on here and how do I fix it?

Notes:

The "alerts" are for testing the code.
The code works when it runs in firefox.
My google chrome version is 30.0.1599.101

Feel free to ask any questions, they will be answered as soon as possible, thanks.

Comment: Can you post an example here? I'm not clicking on anything out of your dropbox.

Comment: An example in jsfiddle is more than welcome

Comment: Even if you knew a specific browser always used the first or the last, this isn't a good idea.

Comment: Use a switch statement or learn what `else if` is.

Comment: Have you tried writing code using two functions with the same name and see what happens? Should be easy to test if you just put an alert in both of them with different messages. As for variables I would assume it just takes the last definition of the variable.

Comment: Scon: The code must be *in the question itself*.

Comment: I had trouble indenting it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 8):

Chrome, or more accurately V8, does what the specification *tells* it to do, in [§10.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5) *(warning: it's really heavy going)*.

#### `var`

If you have multiple `var x;` declarations for the same symbol in the same scope, it's irrelevant, and the second one has no effect at all. **But**, note that `var x = 1;` (e.g., with an initializer) is *really* `var x;` and, separately, `x = 1;`. Only the `var x;` part is ignored if you repeat it, the assignment is not.

So:

```
var x = 5;
var x;
console.log(x); // 5
var x = 42;
console.log(x); // 42
```

...because that code really represents this:

```
var x;
x = 5;
console.log(x); // 5
x = 42;
console.log(x); // 42
```

More: [*Poor misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html) *(article on my blog)*

#### Function Declarations

If you have multiple function *declarations* using the same name in the same scope, the last one wins.

```
foo(); // "foo the second!"

function foo() {
    console.log("foo the first!");
}

function foo() {
    console.log("foo the second!");
}
```

Function *declarations* are different from function *expressions*. The above are declarations. We know that because the function reference isn't immediately being used in an expression (it's not on the right-hand side of an `=`, being passed into another function as an argument, etc.). Function *declarations* occur when execution enters the context in which they're defined, before any step-by-step code runs at all.

#### Function Expressions

Function *expressions*, on the other hand, are processed when the step-by-step execution reaches them, just like any other expression:

```
//foo(); // This would be an error

var foo = function() {
    console.log("foo the first!");
};

foo(); // "foo the first!"

foo = function() {
    console.log("foo the second!");
};

foo(); // "foo the second!"
```

Comment: That is what I was thinking would happen and pretty easy to test.